# Merge two objects and enhance result by adding a new key

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming

I have two objects at the moment (one JSON Schema and one as a response from our API) which I want to merge for better mapping and usage.

The Schema looks like this:

```
// schema
{
  key: {
    description: "foo", 
    properties: {
      values: {
        title: "foo",
        type: "Array"
      },
      type: "string"
    },
    type: "object"
  },
  foo: {
    title: "title",
    description: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    title: "title",
    description: "who"
  }
}
```

And my response object is similar to this:

```
// response
{
  key: {
    values: [0, 1]
    type: "point"
  },
  foo: null,
  bar: "some string"
}
```

I would simply like to merge those two objects, but using `const mergedObject = {...schema, ...response}` would cause overriding the values.

So my desired outcome would contain a new object prop called `value` or something which contains the values of the `response` object:

```
{
  key: {
    value: {
      values: [0, 1],
      type: "point",
    },
    description: "foo", 
    properties: {
      values: {
        title: "foo",
        type: "Array"
      },
      type: "string"
    },
    type: "object"
  },
  foo: {
    value: null,
    title: "title",
    description: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    value: "some string",
    title: "title",
    description: "who"
  }
}
```

Is this doable using the spread operator? I couldn't find a decent solution here since lodashs `assign` or `assignIn` don't provide that functionality either.

I tried this function as well:

```
function merge (...objs) =>
  [...objs].reduce(
    (acc, obj) =>
      Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, k) => {
        acc[k] = acc.hasOwnProperty(k) ? [].concat(acc[k]).concat(obj[k]) : obj[k];
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    {}
  );
```

but it gives me

```
{
  bar: [
    {
      title: "title",
      description: "who"
    },
    "some string",
  ],
  foo: [
    {
      title: "title",
      description: "bar",
    },
    null
  ],
  key: [
    {
      description: "foo", 
      properties: {
        values: {
          title: "foo",
          type: "Array"
        },
        type: "string"
      },
      type: "object"
    },
    {
      values: [0, 1]
      type: "point"
    }
  ]
}
```

which is also not what i want.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [Object.keys(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const objA = {
  key: {
    description: "foo", 
    properties: {
      values: {
        title: "foo",
        type: "Array"
      },
      type: "string"
    },
    type: "object"
  },
  foo: {
    title: "title",
    description: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    title: "title",
    description: "who"
  }
}

const objB = {
  key: {
    values: [0, 1],
    type: "point"
  },
  foo: null,
  bar: "some string"
}


function mergeObjects (objectA, objectB) {

    const mergedObject = {};

    Object.keys(objectA).forEach((key) => {
       mergedObject[key] = {
          ...objectA[key],
          value: typeof objectB[key] === 'object' && objectB[key] !== null 
            ? { ...objectB[key] } 
            : objectB[key]
        }
    })

  return mergedObject;
}

console.log(mergeObjects(objA, objB));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into this

```js
 const data = {
  key: {
description: 'foo', 
properties: {
  values: {
    title: 'foo',
    type: 'Array',
  },
  type: 'string',
},
type: 'object',
  },
  foo: {
title: 'title',
description: 'bar',
  },
  bar: {
title: 'title',
description: 'who',
  },
};

const res = {
  key: {
values: [0, 1],
type: 'point',
  },
  foo: null,
  bar: 'some string',
};

const output = { ...data };

Object.keys(res).forEach((r) => {
  const isPresent = !!(data[r]);
  if (isPresent) {
const responseValues = res[r];
output[r] = { responseValues, ...data[r] };
  } else {
output[r] = res[r];
  }
});

console.log(output);
```